# Can't access Magento 2.2.1 admin,

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, module, admin

Can't access Magento 2.2.1 admin, Stores > Configuration, anyone have this error before? How I can fix this.

Thank you

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/public_html/app/code/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer/Helper/Data.php on line 724

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/public_html/app/code/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer/Helper/Data.php on line 724
#0 /home/public_html/app/code/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer/Helper/Data.php(724): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/...', 724, Array)
#1 /home/public_html/app/code/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer/Helper/Data.php(665): Apptrian\ImageOptimizer\Helper\Data->loadIndex()
#2 /home/public_html/app/code/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer/Block/Adminhtml/Stats.php(47): Apptrian\ImageOptimizer\Helper\Data->getFileCount()
#3 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php(73): Apptrian\ImageOptimizer\Block\Adminhtml\Stats->_getElementHtml(NULL)
#4 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php(52): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field->_renderValue(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Button))
#5 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php(454): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field->render(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Button))
#6 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php(468): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->getHtml()
#7 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Fieldset.php(86): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->toHtml()
#8 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Fieldset.php(66): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Fieldset->_getChildrenElementsHtml(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset))
#9 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php(454): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Fieldset->render(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset))
#10 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php(468): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->getHtml()
#11 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form.php(325): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->toHtml()
#12 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form.php(340): Magento\Framework\Data\Form->toHtml()
#13 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php(101): Magento\Framework\Data\Form->getHtml()
#14 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/form.phtml(15): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->getFormHtml()
#15 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/...')
#16 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form), '/home/...', Array)
#17 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/...')
#18 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#20 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#21 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('system\\config\\f...')
#22 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('system\\config\\f...')
#23 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('system\\config\\f...')
#24 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('system\\config\\f...', true)
#25 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(507): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('system\\config\\f...', true)
#26 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Block/System/Config/Edit/Interceptor.php(479): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('form', true)
#27 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/edit.phtml(22): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit\Interceptor->getChildHtml('form')
#28 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/...')
#29 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit\Interceptor), '/home/...', Array)
#30 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Block/System/Config/Edit/Interceptor.php(245): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/...')
#31 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit\Interceptor->fetchView('/home/...')
#32 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#33 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#34 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#35 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('toHtml', Array)
#36 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#37 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Block/System/Config/Edit/Interceptor.php(572): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('toHtml', Array, Array)
#38 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit\Interceptor->toHtml()
#39 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('system.config.e...')
#40 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('system.config.e...')
#41 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('system.config.e...')
#42 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('system.config.e...', true)
#43 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('system.config.e...')
#44 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#45 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#46 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#47 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#48 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#49 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('admin.scope.col...')
#50 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col...')
#51 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col...')
#52 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('admin.scope.col...', true)
#53 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('admin.scope.col...')
#54 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.col')
#55 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.col')
#56 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.col')
#57 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.col', true)
#58 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.col')
#59 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...')
#60 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#61 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#62 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...', true)
#63 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.conta...')
#64 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content')
#65 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#66 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#67 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', true)
#68 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content')
#69 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#70 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#71 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#72 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#73 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#74 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page')
#75 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#76 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#77 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', true)
#78 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page')
#79 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#80 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#81 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#82 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#83 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#84 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(492): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#85 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#86 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#87 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#88 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#89 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#90 /home/public_html/index.php(57): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

Comment: Please disable module Apptrian_ImageOptimizer for a while and check if admin is working or not. If yes, then you need to debug into Apptrian_ImageOptimizer module.

Comment: @DharaBhatti when I try to disable this module I have this error: public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework): Directory not empty

Comment: Run this command: rm -rf generated/ var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/*

Comment: @DharaBhatti I try that command is the same error when try to disable the module

Comment: My next move would be to look at line 724 of the file that is causing the error and edit it as necessary to avoid whatever the problem is. No need to "fix" anything, since whatever the problem is doesn't seem like it is needed just to view the admin. You can also try renaming that module's etc/admin/system.xml to etc/admin/system.xml.off and clear the cache from the command line. That might temporarily stop it from blocking the rest of the configurations.

Comment: @jiheison at that line I have this: $file['t'] = (int) $l[2];

Comment: It might be possible to get useful information about the problem by adding var_dump($l); just above this line to display the array deatails above the current output. Other than that, I would just try to determine a graceful way to prevent this code from running, i.e. adding a conditional based on count($l). If that isn't possible, you could also look at the containing method to see if returning null, [], {} etc. right away is a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please run below both command and check your adminm

```
php bin/magento module:disable Apptrian_ImageOptimizer 
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

hope this helps you :)

Comment: you have read the discussion with @DharaBhatti  from top? there I say this: when I try to disable this module I have this error: public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework): Directory not empty, how I can disable that module?

Comment: Please go to app/etc/config.php  search your module and please change 1 to 0 and clear cache and run compile comand